# How to style grouped checkboxes from CheckboxSelectMultiple in django with crispy_form

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Here is my form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'flat'}))

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['bar', 'baz']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = (
            ('Groupe1', (
                (1, 'Item1'),
                (2, 'Item2'),            
            )),
            ('Groupe2', (
                (1, 'Item1'),
                (2, 'Item2'),
            )),
        )

        self.fields["foo"].choices = choices
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'myform_id'
        self.helper.form_class = 'myform_class'
        self.helper.form_method = 'GET'
        self.helper.use_custom_control = True
        self.helper.label_class = 'font-weight-bold'
```

Once rendered, I would like to change the style of the group labels. But I don't know how to access it. When I inspect my form, I see the structure looks like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <strong>Groupe1</strong>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label class="" for="id_actes_select_0_0"> 
                    <div class="icheckbox_flat-green" style="position: relative;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="Item1" class="flat" id="id_actes_select_0_0">
                    </div>
                    Item1
                </label>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Group labels are wrapped in `strong tags`. I would like to style them in css. How to do it with crispy_form ?